# SyntaxError: "Unexpected end of input" when trying to authenticate from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration

Can someone help me out on why I'm getting this error message when I'm trying to authenticate to another Salesforce Org?

```
const url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=<consumerKey>&client_secret=<consumerSecret>&username=<username>&password=<password>";

const body = {};

const options = {
   'method' : 'POST',
   'mode' : 'no-cors',
   'headers' : {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'<org domain>',
      'Accept' : '*/*',
      'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
      'Content-Length' : '0'
    },
    'credentials' : 'same-origin',
    'body' : JSON.stringify(body)
};


fetch(url,options).then((response)=>response.json()).then((data)=>{
      console.log('DATA: '+ JSON.stringify(data));
   }).catch(error=>{
      console.error('ERROR: '+ JSON.stringify(error.message));
   });
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: A few things about this strike me as insecure and a bad idea. Particular if any of these secrets aren't known to end users, surfacing them client-side will make them readily available to any user who knows how to use their browser console. Even if the user provides these secrets themselves, sending them in clear text via URL parameters makes them ripe for interception.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewSouther! Instead of saving the URL in a variable, I'm now directly providing the URL inside fetch(), but I still see the same error message.

Comment: I still can't see how you are going to achieve this in LWC without ultimately exposing the password and client secret to end users. Salesforce themselves may be blocking this type of behavior. It's better to use Apex for callouts.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewSouther.